# translate a modifier key (Super to Ctrl OS X)

Tags: key-bindings, osx

Most of the convenient OS X keybindings that GNU Emacs defines, such as `s-a` for `C-x h`, are not all that useful to me. I'd like to make Super synonymous with Ctrl. Is there a way to easily map all key chords involving Super to the equivalent Ctrl version? Failing that, is there a way to map a key to another key that works for prefix keys as well as non-prefix keys?

I've tried using `keyboard-translate` and `global-set-key` so far.

`(keyboard-translate (kbd "s-a") (kbd "C-a"))` results in a type error. I'm not sure why.

`(global-set-key (kbd "s-a") (kbd "C-a"))` works fine, but `(global-set-key (kbd "s-h") (kbd "C-h"))` does not seem to do much of anything.

Comment: If you are using the GUI version of Emacs instead of the terminal, then perhaps this answer will help:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/34933409/2112489  You can modify it as you see fit.  For any variable listed, just type `M-x describe-variable` or `C-h v` to learn more about the available options.

Comment: That does solve the immediate problem, but I'm a little curious why `keyboard-translate` didn't work as intended and why using `global-set-key` and the like works differently for prefix keys. It might be more appropriate to structure those as separate questions or hunt around more, I'm not sure.

Comment: Another forum participant will need to help with `keyboard-translate` as I've never used it.  I have set up my own keyboard shortcuts and disabled those that I didn't find useful, so I have no need to remap anything.  Sorry that I couldn't be of more assistance.

Answer (score 1):

So I think:

```
(keyboard-translate (kbd "s-a") (kbd "C-a"))
```

results in a type error because `keyboard-translate` takes character parameters, but `kbd` returns an "internal Emacs key representation", something very different than a character.

Also I don't think your use of `global-set-key` is doing what you think it's doing: when you say `(global-set-key (kbd "s-a") (kbd "C-a"))`, you are actually binding the key `s-a` to the *output of the command* `(kbd "C-a")`.  Apparently (surprisingly, to me) that happens to do what you meant for a single-key command, but it makes sense to me that it wouldn't work at all for prefix-map keybindings.

As lawlist said in the link in their comment, setting `ns-command-modifier` is the  way to do what you want here.

Comment: I still don't follow why `(kbd "C-a")` doesn't give do what I want in the case of prefix keys. I thought that `kbd` just maps from a human-readable string notation for sequence of keys to an internal representation that makes sense to emacs. I guess the fundamental question here is why mapping a key to a key works in some cases but not others. I still don't have a good intuition there. I've been using the `ns-command-modifier` workaround for the past few months and haven't had any problems with it.

Comment: OK, so for prefix commands, e.g. `C-h` is bound to a special value that says  it can be used as a prefix. When you `(global-set-key (kbd "s-h")  (kbd "C-h"))`, you aren't binding S-h as a prefix key, you are binding it to the output of `(kbd "C-h")`, which is just a string. So striking S-h will invoke a string, which doesn't do anything. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Adding another option in case someone is looking for different solutions.

If the Super => Control mapping is only desired in GUI Emacs (on macOS), one can use [Karabiner Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements) (FOSS) with the appropriate "complex modification." These are the steps:

1. Put this in a file, like `super_to_control_on_emacs.json`:

   ```
   { "title": "Super to Ctrl on Emacs",
     "rules": [
       { "description": "Turn Command (Super) into Ctrl on Emacs",
         "manipulators": [
           { "type": "basic",
             "from": { "key_code": "left_command",
                       "modifiers": { "optional": ["any"] } },
             "to": [ { "key_code": "left_control" } ],
             "conditions": [ { "type": "frontmost_application_if",
                               "bundle_identifiers": ["^org\\.gnu\\.Emacs$"] } ] },
           { "type": "basic",
             "from": { "key_code": "right_command",
                       "modifiers": { "optional": ["any"] }},
             "to": [ { "key_code": "right_control" } ],
             "conditions": [ { "type": "frontmost_application_if",
                               "bundle_identifiers": [ "^org\\.gnu\\.Emacs$" ] } ] } ] } ] }
   ```
2. Copy it to `~/.config/karabiner/assets/complex_modifications/`
3. Open **Karabiner Elements > Complex Modifications > Add Rule > Turn Command (Super) into Ctrl on Emacs > Enable**. That's it!

This template can be used for other Emacs-specific modifications as well.